# Django Query for current stock list from operations table field with IN, OUT value and field with date and time

Tags: django, django-queryset

Django Query for below case to find list of available stock based on ops_type=IN entry with date and time and ops_type=OUT entry with date and time.

*date and time field are separate because the data is uploaded from sheet and needs to be in same format to process.*

Operations model is as follows

```
class Operations(BaseModel):
    class OPS(IntEnum):
        IN = 0
        OUT = 1

        @classmethod
        def choices(cls):
            return [(key.value, key.name) for key in cls]

    date = models.DateField()
    time = models.TimeField(default=None, null=True)
    ops_type = models.IntegerField(choices=OPS.choices())
    serial = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None, null=True, db_index=True)
    product = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=None)
```

**Error:** Cannot resolve keyword 'latest_out_datetime' into field. Join on 'serial' not permitted.

```
from django.db.models import F, Q, Subquery, OuterRef, ExpressionWrapper, DateTimeField
from datetime import datetime

in_entries = Operations.objects.filter(ops_type=Operations.OPS.IN.value)

out_entries = Operations.objects.filter(
    ops_type=Operations.OPS.OUT.value,
    serial=OuterRef('serial')
).values('serial').annotate(
    latest_out_datetime=Subquery(
        Operations.objects.filter(
            ops_type=Operations.OPS.OUT.value,
            serial=OuterRef('serial')
        ).annotate(
            datetime=ExpressionWrapper(F('date') + F('time'), output_field=DateTimeField())
        ).order_by('-datetime').values('datetime')[:1]
    )
)

available_stock = in_entries.annotate(
    in_datetime=ExpressionWrapper(F('date') + F('time'), output_field=DateTimeField()),
    latest_out_datetime=F('serial__latest_out_datetime')
).filter(
    Q(latest_out_datetime__isnull=True) | Q(in_datetime__gt=F('latest_out_datetime'))
)

stock_list = [stock.serial for stock in available_stock]

print("List of available stock:", stock_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

Some of the code here does not make sense. For example why do you have two OuterRef in `out_entries`? Why it is not wrapped with Subquery?

I think you are making the implementation overcomplicated here. I think you can simply try like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q, Max, F

in_entries = Operations.objects.annotate(
    datetime=ExpressionWrapper(
        F('date') + F('time'),
        output_field=DateTimeField()
    )
   .values('serial')
   .annotate(
        max_out_date=Max(
            'datetime',
            filter=Q(
                serial=F('serial'),
                ops_type=Operations.OPS.OUT.value
            )
        )
    ).filter(ops_type=Operations.OPS.IN.value).values('serial', 'max_out_date')
```

For more information, please see the [Django aggregation cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet) in the documentation.